# Google Chrome Browser is enlarged

Tags: google-chrome

My Google chrome browser is enlarged. It has nothing to do with zoom. If I make the zoom smaller all it does is affect the text. The tabs are enlarged so are the close, minimize and restore down buttons.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

How can I get it back to normal again?

Answer (score 0):

I think the accessibility feature for 'Larger Text' is on. Go to the menu in the upper right hand corner, settings, "Show advanced settings...", and "Web content". In that set "Font size" to "Medium" and "Page zoom" to 100% (just in case).

Picture of the settings page:

[image: settings]
([http://imgur.com/QKYxzQZ](https://imgur.com/QKYxzQZ))